# A question about a formula for lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have been asking a number of questions about fitting mixed effects models. Thanks to a number of wonderful statisticians on here I have come far, and I thank you for you continued patience. I was going to ask this question live in chat but when I officially registered my username I lost my reputation and it has reverted from 23 to 1, so I apologise for yet another question.

I now understand how to formulate a simple mixed-effects model, enter into the R package using lme4 and how to look at AICc etc. to compare models. However, one response variable may need a more complex design which I would appreciate help with if at all possible.

I wish to see if habitat choice of broods at one site is different from the other. Each observation may have multiple habitats used so I have a proportion of use for each habitat type for each observation. I have six broods, three at each site. 
Maybe an alternate test is better, but as I only have six broods that I wish to compare (three at each beach) so using means makes the sample very small, and I cannot use chi-sq due to it being proportional data. So, I am not sure if a formula is available in a model that would then allow me to compare it to a null model to see if site has an effect on the response variable 'habitat'. However I have 7 habitats so have a variable (proportion of use) for each habitat within each observation.

More importantly I would like to see how the use of each habitat affects a response variable such as mean foraging rate. Another study did this but their model contain one variable 'habitat' which made me think that they had only one habitat per observation. However they ended up calculating the Estimate for each habitat by averaging the two top models (AIC delta<2), so it seems that it may have somehow contained a formula showing each habitat use within?) The easy way would be just to add a variable for each habitat, but feel that they should be 'related' in some way. However I would still like to get an Estimate for each habitat.

I hope that I am making sense.

Comment: If habitat is a factor with different levels for the different types of habitat, then you can get information on the effects of different habitat types by entering it into your model as a fixed effect.

The comparisons that will be made between different types of habitats are determined by the contrasts that have been set for that factor, you can see these by running `contrasts(yourdataframe$habitat)`. The default contrasts compare a reference level of habitat to each of the other levels.

Comment: I think this is what I need. I know that it may be asking too much, but is there any way that you could tell me how I would do this in R by any chance as my syntax knowledge is limited. I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Actually, I just realised what you meant. Unfortunately the habitat is not one variable as there is a value for each habitat for each observation. For example one brood may have spent 40% of their time in one habitat and then 60% in another, and the rest would have a 0 value. I wasn't sure if a fixed effect could somehow be built with these separate values, or is there a way of adding them so that their combined effect can be looked at, but still able to give me a relative Estimate for each to see how important each habitat is.